# Ordering ObservableCollection with Linq and IComparer

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, icomparer

I want to order alphabetically an ObservableCollection because I don't wanna have to create another binding. I've seen we could use Linq and the method OrderBy. I would like also to use a personal IComparer because I will have to organize complex datas (lists into other lists), but VS tells me I can't use my own comparer :

(give you the link of the error because my VS is in french)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hxfhx4sy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Any ideas ?

```
private void SortGraphicObjectsAscending(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicObjects.OrderBy(graphicObject => graphicObject.Nom, new GraphicObjectComparer(true));

    }
```

And my own comparer (which is already tested)

```
public class GraphicObjectComparer : IComparer<GraphicObject>
{
    int order = 1;

    public GraphicObjectComparer(Boolean ascending)
    {
        if (!ascending)
        {
            order = -1;
        }
    }

    public GraphicObjectComparer()
    {

    }

    public int Compare(GraphicObject x, GraphicObject y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.Nom, y.Nom, false) * order;
    }

}
```

---

Thanks for your answers. Anyway I have another problem. As Michael said, I use a more complex comparer but for another entity. This entity is displayed with a hierarchical tree, and an object might contain a list of other objects of the same type.

I couldn't test an my GraphicObject becuse I don't have access to the DB (there was no object at the moment). With the tests on my VideoEntity it seems my ObservableCollection is not sorted the way I want (I create another one). I want to reverse it alphabetically but it doesn't work.

```
public class VideoEntityComparer : IComparer<VideoEntity>
{

    int order = 1;

    public VideoEntityComparer(Boolean ascending)
    {
        if (!ascending)
        {
            this.order = -1; // so descending
        }
    }

    public VideoEntityComparer()
    {

    }

    public int Compare(VideoEntity x, VideoEntity y)
    {
        if ((x is BaseDirectory && y is BaseDirectory) || (x is BaseSite && y is BaseSite) || (x is VideoEncoder && y is VideoEncoder))
        {
            return string.Compare(x.Nom, y.Nom, false) * order; // only objects of the same type are sorted alphabetically
        }
        else if ((x is BaseDirectory && y is BaseSite) || (x is BaseSite && y is VideoEncoder))
        {
            return -1;
        }else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void SortDirectoriesDescending(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<BaseDirectory> tempDir  = new ObservableCollection<BaseDirectory>(
            Directories.OrderBy(directory => directory, new VideoEntityComparer(false)));
        Directories = tempDir;
    }
```

PS : by the way, I'm acting on a DependancyProperty. Is it the correct way to do it ? (I'm new on WPF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that line is in the definition of `OrderBy` that you're trying to use:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

There are two different generic parameters to this method: `TSource` and `TKey`. `TSource` is obvious, it's the same as the `TSource` for the source `IEnumerable`. The `TKey` parameter is the one that the compiler is trying, and failing, to infer because you are trying to use two different types. Your call:

```
GraphicObjects.OrderBy(graphicObject => graphicObject.Nom, new GraphicObjectComparer(true));
```

Your first parameter is a `Func<GraphicObject, string>` but your second parameter is an `IComparer<GraphicObject>`; this means you're using `TKey = string` in one place and `TKey = GraphicObject` in the other.

The first parameter, the `Func<>` delegate, is the "key selector"; it's how you tell `OrderBy` which values to sort by. Since your `IComparer<>` is sorting based on the *entire `GraphicObject` instance*, that's what you should be selecting as your key:

```
GraphicObjects.OrderBy(go => go, new GraphicObjectComparer(true));
```

I'm assuming that your custom comparer object is actually more complex than what you've shown, because your sample comparer is pretty redundant:

```
var asc = GraphicObjects.OrderBy(go => go.Nom);
var desc = GraphicObjects.OrderByDescending(go => go.Nom);
```

Also, note that you're sample code isn't actually doing anything with the newly-sorted list, so it's just getting thrown out. LINQ operations *never* change the source enumerable, they always return a new, transformed copy of it instead.

Answer (score 1):

your `comparer` compares `GraphicObject`. so your `OrderBy` should be

```
 GraphicObjects.OrderBy(graphicObject => graphicObject,
                                                 new GraphicObjectComparer(true));
```

or just use

```
GraphicObjects.OrderBy(graphicObject => graphicObject.Nom);
```

BTW, `OrderBy` doesn't sort in-place, you should assign the returned `IEnumerable<GraphicsObject>` to a variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Comparer uses GraphicObject, but you compare strings.

If you really need your own ordering, you can use this Comparer:

```
public class GraphicObjectComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    int order = 1;

    public GraphicObjectComparer(Boolean ascending)
    {
        if (!ascending)
        {
            order = -1;
        }
    }

    public GraphicObjectComparer()
    {

    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x, y, false) * order;
    }
}
```

Or you provide a GraphicObject to your comparer, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sorted ObservableCollection reflects all the changes in  the source collection you can use my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. Using this library you can code like this:

```C#
var sortedGraphicObjects = GraphicObjects.Ordering(
    graphicObject => graphicObject.Nom, new GraphicObjectComparer(true));
```

sortedGraphicObjects is ObservableCollection and reflects all the changes in the GraphicObjects collection and Nom property. Ensure that Nom property notifies of changes through the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface.